# Error storing Topic Model into the database using Sentinel

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5.1, laravel-5

I have a small forum, im trying to create topic and replies for the store method.

**routes.php**

```
Route::get('board/{id}/create', 'TopicsController@create');
Route::post('board/{id}/create', 'TopicsController@store');
```

**TopicsController.php**

```
public function store()
{
    $this->request->user()->topics()->create([
        'board_id' => $this->request->id,
        'title' => $this->request->title,
        'body' => $this->request->body
    ]);
    return redirect(url('/board/' . $this->request->id));
}
```

I am receiving this error.

```
Call to a member function topics() on null
```

Also note, i am using Sentinel https://github.com/rydurham/Sentinel from this repo.

```
<?php namespace App\Models;


class User extends \Sentinel\Models\User
{

    protected $fillable = ['email', 'first_name', 'last_name'];

    protected $hidden = ['password'];

    public function topics()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Topic::class);
    }

    public function replies()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Reply::class);
    }

    public function getGravatarAttribute()
    {
        $hash = md5(strtolower(trim($this->attributes['email'])));
        return "https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/$hash";
    }
}
```

Updated Model

```
public function store($id)
    {
        $user = Sentry::getUser($id);

        $user->topics()->create([
            'board_id' => $this->request->id,
            'title' => $this->request->title,
            'body' => $this->request->body
        ]);
        return redirect(url('/board/' . $this->request->id));
    }
```

Comment: Can you show your route?

Comment: You should use implicit binding to get the user. Now it is null

Comment: Route::get('board/{id}/create', 'TopicsController@create');
    Route::post('board/{id}/create', 'TopicsController@store');

Comment: If you can include the user model is helpful as well

Comment: i updated the User model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your user object is null. Properly retrieve the user using the id

```
public function store($id)
{

    $user = \App\Models\User::find(\Sentinel::getUser()->id);

    $user->topics()->create([
        'board_id' => $this->request->id,
        'title' => $this->request->title,
        'body' => $this->request->body
    ]);
    return redirect(url('/board/' . $this->request->id));
}
```

Comment: Model has namespace App\Models and im using senitel, that requires a wrapper Sentry::getUser

Comment: no it's not working. https://github.com/rydurham/Sentinel/issues/37 check this out.